# Drilling down child array swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I am trying to drill this object down to `transitions` from `[Datum]` but every time I use a flatMap, I simply get the same array back.

Transaction expected is `var transactions: [String]?`

I however feel if I continue to drill down using flatMap continuously like this

```
let transactions = reportSummaryDictionary.flatMap { dictionary in
}
```

I would end up with a really messy codebase. any help on how I can better drill down to transactions

```
struct Datum: Codable {
    var summary: [DatumSummary]?
}

// MARK: - DatumSummary
struct DatumSummary: Codable {
    var summary: SummarySummary?
}

// MARK: - SummarySummary
struct SummarySummary: Codable {
    var startingBalance: Int?
    var report: [Report]?
}

// MARK: - Report
struct Report: Codable {
    var summary: [ReportSummaryx]?
    var transactions: [Transactionx]?
    
    // MARK: - ReportSummary
    struct ReportSummaryx: Codable {
        var amount: Int?
        var category: String?
    }

    // MARK: - Transaction
    struct Transactionx: Codable {
        var category: String?
        var transactions: [String]?
    }
}
```

Comment: I see 2 properties named `transactions`, which one do you mean and what is the expected result here? And why have you made everything optional?

Comment: this is the expected one. `var transactions: [String]?` I have edited my question to reflect this. The expected result is an array of  `[String]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than trying to come up with a one-liner I decided to make this step-by-step

```
let step1 = datum.compactMap(\.summary).flatMap { $0 }
let step2 = step1.compactMap(\.summary).compactMap(\.report).flatMap { $0 }
let step3 = step2.compactMap(\.transactions).flatMap { $0 }
let transactions = step3.compactMap(\.transactions).flatMap { $0 }
```

Comment: I like the step-wise approach. It's easier to follow, and MUCH easier to debug.